# Where to put layout code

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, lifecycle

I need some code to run in a component after all the sizes of its children are known. The component has an absolute layout. I thought my component's measure() function would get called after all it's children's measure() functions had been called, but it seems like since it has an absolute layout, it never even calls measure.

Anyways, it's a Canvas and my `override protected function measure():void` never runs. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updateDisplayList() is called in UIComponent's commitProperties.  I believe this is called after the child sizes are known, and it is where you are supposed to put your layout code.

measure() is not called when you explicitly set a width and height on your components.  If you have an absolute layout on your Canvas, but do not set a width and height, measure() will be called.

HTH;

Amy

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to override anything, simply add a listener to the creationComplete of your component. This event is "Dispatched when the component has finished its construction, property processing, measuring, layout, and drawing."

Example where the component inherits from s:Group

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400" height="300"
     creationComplete="group1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        protected function group1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            //TODO add code here
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
</s:Group>
```

Comment: Yeah, I realize creationComplete will work, but it will be kind of wasteful to wait until the component is finished drawing and then change the layout and make it draw again. I was hoping to catch it somewhere between measurement and drawing

Comment: You should use the initialize event (called when all childs have been added) or the render event (called just before rendering) then instead of creationComplete. I would try to go with initialize first